# Swap elements in Linked List

Tags: c, data-structures

I've been trying to swap elements in a linked list. The swapping needs to be done with the third element from the beginning and the third element from the end. I've tried implementing a **Doubly Linked List** and try to iterate from the last node to find the third position from the last node. Ended up with a Singly Linked List.

I came up with the following solution:

- Find the third element from the beginning of the list.
- Subtract (length - position) and find the next element.

I can't figure out where I am wrong, I've looked up couple of different solutions but can't figure out why it's not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

Node *head = NULL;

void insert();
void display();
void swap();

int main()
{
    int choice;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("\n1.Insert beginning\n");
        printf("2.Display\n");
        printf("3.Swap\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
          case 1:
            {
                insert();
                break;
            }
          case 2:
            {
                display();
                break;
            }
          case 3:
            {
                swap();
                break;
            }
          default:
            {
                printf("Error!\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void insert()
{
    Node *current;
    current = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (current == NULL)
    {
        printf("Out of memory!\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("Enter a value \n");
    scanf("%d", &current->data);
    current->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = current;
    }
    else
    {
        current->next = head;
        head = current;
    }
}

void display()
{
    Node *temp;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty!\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ", temp->data);
            temp = temp -> next;
        }
    }
}

void swap()
{
    Node *current1, *current2, *prev1, *prev2, *temp;
    temp = NULL;
    int k;
    int n;
    printf("Enter a range: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter a pos: \n");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    prev1 = NULL;
    prev2 = NULL;
    current1 = head;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        current1 = current1->next;
        if (i == k)
        {
            prev1 = current1;
        }
    }
    current2 = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - k - 1; ++i)
    {
        prev2 = current2;
        current2 = current2->next;
    }

    prev1->next = current2;
    prev2->next = current1;

    temp = current1->next;
    current1->next = current2->next;
    current2->next = temp;
}
```

Note: `k` - is the position of the element that needs to be swapped(same position from beginning and same from the end);
`N` - is the length of the list starting from index `0`

**Edit:** I've included the main function, display of the list function and insert an element in the beginning.

**Sample Input:**

```
10 3
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

**Sample Output:**

```
1 2 3 7 5 6 4 8 9 10
```

**Edit:** added `main` function, display and insert element in the beginning.

**Edit:** when I input it does not swap the elements, instead it exits the program.

Comment: Aside: In a case like this, it would be much simpler to 'swap' the payload values of the two nodes (rather than mucking around with "previous node's pointers" x 2)...

Comment: My ideea was that previous nodes links also need to be pointing to the other node. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Soo.... what's not working? Does it crash? Does it output `1 2 7 3 5 6 4 8 9 10` for the sample output? Could you be more clear about that part, or do you simply expect people to figure out what's not working in your code and propose a solution to that problem? :)

Comment: First loop should run only till k and if check inside it can be eliminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in a comment, it would be much simpler to find the two nodes involved in the swap and swap the payload (`int data;`) of those two nodes.

Following is an annotated rewrite of the OP code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

// Avoid using global variables. 'head' is passed as a parameter to functions

// Function definitions preceding use do not require prototypes

Node *insert( Node *head, int val ) {
    Node *n = malloc( sizeof *n );
    /* Omitting test for failure */
    n->data = val;
    n->next = head; // simpler
    return n;
}

void display( Node *n ) { // standard LL display functionality
    if( !n )
        puts( "List is empty!" );
    else {
        for( ; n; n = n->next )
            printf( "%d ", n->data );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

void swap( Node *probe, int n ) {
    Node *follower = probe; // 'follower' starts at list's first node
    for( int i = 0; i < n && probe; i++ ) // advance 'probe' to position 'n'
        probe = probe->next;

    if( !probe )
        puts( "Impossible" );
    else {
        Node *first = probe; // remember this as 'first' node of interest

        while( probe->next ) { // advance both 'probe' and 'follower' 
            follower = follower->next;
            probe = probe->next;
        }
        // 'follower' will be 'n' nodes "behind" the probe that's reached end of the LL

        // Merely swap the two nodes' payloads... Simple!
        int temp = first->data;
        first->data = follower->data;
        follower->data = temp;
    }
}

int main( void ) {
    Node *head = NULL; // local variable, not global

    for( int i = 1; i < 10; i++ ) // create a LL of 9 nodes
        head = insert( head, i );

    display( head );

    // try swapping 0th, 1st, 2nd, ...
    for( int s = 0; s < 10; s++ ) {
        swap( head, s ); 
        display( head );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 // original
1 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 9 // swapped 0th from both ends of LL
1 2 7 6 5 4 3 8 9 // ...
1 2 3 6 5 4 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 6 5 4 7 8 9
1 2 7 6 5 4 3 8 9
1 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 9
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
Impossible // Attempting to swap beyond the boundaries of the list
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

This technique does not require foreknowledge of the number of nodes in the list.

If the size of the payload is appreciable, the payload should be stored separately (with its own `malloc()`'d struct), and the nodes then contain only pointers to their respective payloads.

Not shown is this requisite 'clean up', freeing the nodes before exiting.

By using the compile-time creation of the nodes, it is possible to develop and test the code without a lot of (re-)typing data. Adding "user input" functionality to this is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Code updated for case when **k** is 0. Works the same as the original code with some exceptions. Loop only runs till **k** element and if **k** is 0, it means it has no previous node, in which case the head of the list will be the last element from the end of the list. Obviously the last element of the list will have a previous node.

```
void swap()
{
    Node *current1, *current2, *prev1, *prev2, *temp;
    temp = NULL;
    int k;
    int n;
    printf("Enter a range: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter a pos: \n");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    prev1 = NULL;
    prev2 = NULL;
    current1 = head;

    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
    {
        prev1 = current1;
        current1 = current1 -> next;

    }
    current2 = head;
    for (int i = 0; i<n-k-1; ++i)
    {
        prev2 = current2;
        current2 = current2 -> next;
    }


    if (current1 != NULL && current2 != NULL)
    {
        if (prev1 != NULL)
            prev1 -> next = current2;
        if (prev2 != NULL)
            prev2 -> next = current1;
    }


    temp = current1 -> next;
    current1 -> next = current2 -> next;
    current2 -> next = temp;

    if (prev1 == NULL)
    {
        head = current2;
    }
    else if (prev2 == NULL)
    {
        head = current1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is OK to answer your own question. Please [edit] the answer and add some explanation what's wrong with the original code and what you changed to fix it.

Comment: Answers with code and no explanation whatsoever are bad answers.

Comment: Your solution does not allow to swap the very first node (position 0).